# Factorial to Permutation; (n+3)! = 720*n!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, factorial

The problem is : Find $n$ if:

$$(n+3)! = 720 \cdot n!$$

The explanation goes as following:

a) $\frac{(n+3)!}{n!}=720$

b) $_{(n+3)}\text{P}_3 = 720$

c) $_{10}P_3 = 720$

d) $n=7$

What I don't get is how it went from step (a) to (b) and where the $3$ come from?

Comment: What does the notation $nPk$ mean?

Comment: nPk = n!/(n-k)!

Comment: Subscripts/superscripts would have made this a *lot* clearer ...

Comment: @John Don't know how to do it :D

Comment: Another user and I have edited your question. Click on the "edit" link below your question to see how we did it. There's also a post on the meta site on using MathJax; it's the highest-voted post on meta.

Comment: Hiw @John does one get from the stack to meta?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Click on the "talk balloon" icon in the upper right in the navigation bar, and select Meta from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) 
$$\frac{(n+3)!}{n!}=720$$
By definition of factorials
$$\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)[(n)!])}{n!}=720$$
Dividing the numerator and denominator by n!
$$(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=720$$
By definition of $nPk=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$
$$(n+3)P3 = \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+3-3)!}=\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)[(n)!]}{(n)!}=(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)$$
So using $(n+3)P3$
b)
$$(n+3)P3 = 720$$

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it looks like you know what $nPk$ means, so:

$$\frac{(n+3)!}{n!}=\frac{(n+3)!}{[(n+3)-3]!}=_{n+3}P_{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+3)! = 720 \cdot n! \implies \frac {(n+3)!}{n!}=720$$

$$(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=720  \implies (n+3)P3 =720 $$

$$ 720=(10)(9)(8) \implies n=7$$